# How to keep license text in JS and CSS when using Grails Asset-Pipeline plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, asset-pipeline

I am using Grails Asset-Pipeline plugin to manage my assets. Now I want to keep the license-texts contained in some Bower-managed JS and CSS files when compressing JS and CSS during production-build.
There are different ways for a JS-/CSS-library author to define that a comment block should be kept when minifying/compressing, e.g.

```
/*!
 * should be kept
 */

/* @license
 * should be kept
 */

/* @preserve
 * should be kept
 */
```

For JS, only @license and @preserve seem to be respected by Assets-Pipeline. Is there any way to tell it to respect other 'preserve'-hints, too?